# Exception running a simple websocket with Camel component on Jetty

Tags: websocket, jetty, apache-camel

I'm trying to run use Camel Websocket component on Jetty but cannot get rid of the following exception. I'm not sure if this a issue with Jetty running with Camel or issues with versions compatibility or something is missing in my code.

I've put the project on Github in case someone wants to give it a try. 
https://github.com/soumyasd/jettycamelwebsocket

Following are the steps to run the application.

1. Update your Twitter credentials in this class src/main/java/demo/websocket/
2. `$mvn clean install`
3. `$mvn jetty:run`
4. Point your web browser (I used Google Chrome) to `http://localhost:8080/index.html`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketFactory.upgrade(WebSocketFactory.java:236)[jetty-websocket-8.1.9.v20130131.jar:8.1.9.v20130131]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketFactory.acceptWebSocket(WebSocketFactory.java:382)[jetty-websocket-8.1.9.v20130131.jar:8.1.9.v20130131]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketServlet.service(WebSocketServlet.java:104)[jetty-websocket-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)[javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:598)[jetty-servlet-8.1.3.v20120416.jar:8.1.9.v20130131]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:486)[jetty-servlet-8.1.3.v20120416.jar:8.1.9.v20130131]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1065)[jetty-server-8.1.3.v20120416.jar:8.1.9.v20130131]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:413)[jetty-servlet-8.1.3.v20120416.jar:8.1.9.v20130131]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:999)[jetty-server-8.1.3.v20120416.jar:8.1.9.v20130131]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)[jetty-server-8.1.3.v20120416.jar:8.1.9.v20130131]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)[jetty-server-8.1.3.v20120416.jar:8.1.9.v20130131]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:350)[jetty-server-8.1.3.v20120416.jar:8.1.9.v20130131]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:454)[jetty-server-8.1.3.v20120416.jar:8.1.9.v20130131]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:890)[jetty-server-8.1.3.v20120416.jar:8.1.9.v20130131]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:944)[jetty-server-8.1.3.v20120416.jar:8.1.9.v20130131]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:630)[jetty-http-8.1.3.v20120416.jar:8.1.9.v20130131]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:230)[jetty-http-8.1.3.v20120416.jar:8.1.9.v20130131]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:77)[jetty-server-8.1.3.v20120416.jar:8.1.9.v20130131]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:606)[jetty-io-8.1.3.v20120416.jar:8.1.9.v20130131]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:46)[jetty-io-8.1.3.v20120416.jar:8.1.9.v20130131]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:603)[jetty-util-8.1.3.v20120416.jar:8.1.9.v20130131]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:538)[jetty-util-8.1.3.v20120416.jar:8.1.9.v20130131]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)[:1.6.0_45]
```

Here is my main Camel route.

```java
package demo.websocket; 

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.twitter.TwitterComponent;
import org.apache.camel.component.websocket.WebsocketComponent;

public class TwitterStreamRoute extends RouteBuilder{

        //put your twitter keys here to test 
        public final String CONSUMER_KEY = ""; 
        public final String CONSUMER_SECRET = ""; 
        public final String ACCESS_TOKEN = ""; 
        public final String ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = ""; 


        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {




        TwitterComponent tc = getContext().getComponent("twitter", TwitterComponent.class);
        tc.setAccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN);
        tc.setAccessTokenSecret(ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
        tc.setConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
        tc.setConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);

        fromF("twitter://streaming/filter?type=polling&delay=%s&keywords=%s", "5", "pittsburgh")
                .process(new Processor() {
                                @Override
                                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                                        String res = exchange.getIn().getBody().toString();
                                        exchange.getOut().setBody(res);
                                }   
                        })  
        .to("websocket://0.0.0.0:9292/camel-tweet?sendToAll=true");
        }   

}
```

The Camel config looks like the following:

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">


    <!-- Here we define Camel, notice the namespace it uses -->
    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" trace="true">
        <routeBuilder ref="twitter-route-id" ></routeBuilder>
    </camelContext>

    <bean id="twitter-route-id" class="demo.websocket.TwitterStreamRoute" />

</beans>
```

My web.xml looks like

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
        xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
                        id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
                          <!-- your web.xml content here -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:camel-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
                          </web-app>
```

~

I'm using the following versions in my pom.xml. The full pom.xml is [here](https://github.com/soumyasd/jettycamelwebsocket/blob/master/pom.xml).

```xml
    <properties>
            <spring.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
            <camel.version>2.11.0</camel.version>
            <jetty.version>8.1.3.v20120416</jetty.version>
    </properties>
```

**UPDATE (6-May-2013, 3:04 PM EST)**

I updated the pom.xml to use Jetty 7.6.x release as suggested by Claus Ibsen. 
But I'm still getting the same error. Also in this case the stackstrace have the same version numbers for WebSocketFactory and WebSocketServlet.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketFactory.upgrade(WebSocketFactory.java:236)[jetty-websocket-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketFactory.acceptWebSocket(WebSocketFactory.java:382)[jetty-websocket-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketServlet.service(WebSocketServlet.java:104)[jetty-websocket-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)[javax.servlet-2.5.0.v201103041518.jar:]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:652)[jetty-servlet-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:447)[jetty-servlet-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1038)[jetty-server-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:374)[jetty-servlet-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:972)[jetty-server-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)[jetty-server-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)[jetty-server-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:363)[jetty-server-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:483)[jetty-server-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:920)[jetty-server-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)[jetty-server-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:635)[jetty-http-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)[jetty-http-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)[jetty-server-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)[jetty-io-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)[jetty-io-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)[jetty-util-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)[jetty-util-7.6.8.v20121106.jar:7.6.8.v20121106]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)[:1.6.0_32]
```

**UPDATE 2 (6-May-2013 4:06 PM EST)** 
As suggested by @JoakimErdfelt in the comments the Google Chrome file with request response information is [here](https://github.com/soumyasd/jettycamelwebsocket/blob/master/net-internals-log_6May2013_3_51PM_EST.json).

Comment: Your stacktrace says Jetty 8.1.9.v20130131, but your pom says Jetty 8.1.3.v20120416.  That is a bit confusing.

Comment: Yeah that's strange. Let me debug it a little bit more.

Comment: I updated the original question with a new stacktrace.

Comment: Include which version of Google Chrome you used to cause this.  Or better yet, capture your network traffic, HTTP request for upgrade (and HTTP response) and post it.  (Look into the built-in Chrome network inspector or `chrome://net-internals` as techniques).

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt - Thanks. I'll update the Google Chrome version. I get the same error on Google Chrome running on Windows/Linux/OS-X. I'm pretty sure if you clone the git repo you will also get the same error. I'll try get the HTTP request and response.

Comment: Here is the network dump from Google. BTW, this a very cool feature of Chrome. https://github.com/soumyasd/jettycamelwebsocket/blob/master/net-internals-log_6May2013_3_51PM_EST.json

Comment: I see the request at [around line #231](https://github.com/soumyasd/jettycamelwebsocket/blob/master/net-internals-log_6May2013_3_51PM_EST.json#L2311), lets see if standard (non-camel) jetty 7.6.8 is ok with that set of headers.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29506/discussion-between-soumya-simanta-and-joakim-erdfelt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think I've figured out the exact reason behind this error. However, I've a solution that works without major changes to the code.

I believe the problem is with the classloading for websocket related classes in Jetty and the Jetty-maven-plugin. Either my plugin in my pom.xml is not configured properly or I'm missing some entries. In any case, after trying this out for almost a day my alternative solution is as follows:

Instead of using the Jetty-maven-plugin to deploy the application I used Jetty Runner (http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Using_Jetty_Runner) to deploy the application. NOTE: Please download the version that is matches your jetty.version in your pom.xml.

For example:

```
$java -jar jetty-runner-7.6.8.v20121106.jar target/jettycamelwebsocket.war
```

After this I was able to access the websocket from my index.html without any issues.

Now if someone could explain why this doesn't work (or what's missing) from the Jetty-maven-plugin it would be really useful.

Here are a few references that I found useful. Although they are dated some of them gave me a hint that there maybe something wrong with the Jetty Maven Plugin, therefore pointing me the correct direction.

http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg00263.html

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same exception couple of days back. The issue is null `Connection` object. At least for me the root cause was jetty settings. Make sure you have websocket enabled in your jetty start.ini file. Something like this -

```
OPTIONS=Server,jsp,resources,ext,plus,websocket
```

It should be enabled by default, but it wasn't in our case since somebody customized our start.ini and removed websocket support by mistake. After adding it back websocket worked like charm with Jetty 7.6.8.

Comment: Do you know how to set this in the Maven Jetty Plugin ?

Comment: I couldn't find a way to set the options when running with the Maven plugin. However did check the mvn classpath using $mvn -X jetty:run and it has the websocket jars in the classpath. Also see http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg02544.html and  http://paulfeaviour.wordpress.com/2010/04/01/running-websocket-example-with-jetty-mavenplugin

Comment: the `OPTIONS` line simply adds the appropriate jars to the server classpath.  Since the @SoumyaSimanta has those classes present in his stacktrace, it is safe to assume that he's satisfied this requirement.

Comment: You can use `$ java -jar start.jar --version` to see what jars will be present in your server classpath based on the `start.ini` and the `OPTIONS` line.

Comment: I'll have to create a start.jar by embedding Jetty ?

Comment: @SoumyaSimanta Sorry I don't know how to do that. We are not using Maven Jetty plugin. Can you try deploying your app to a vanilla Jetty server and see if it works? You can download the stable versions from here [link](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/)

Answer (score 1):

The NPE on [WebSocketFactory:236](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-8.1.9.v20130131/jetty-websocket/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/WebSocketFactory.java#L233-L236) is due to an attempt to upgrade without arriving in via a real Jetty HTTP connection.

The most common causes for this:

- Attempting to use Jetty WebSockets on a web container that isn't jetty. (such as tomcat or jboss)
- Attempting to unit test your websocket (servlet) without using a real HTTP connection (such as via a mocking library)

Comment: 1. My web container is Jetty. 2. And I'm using a real HTTP connection from (see index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try use Jetty 7.6.x as thats the version we test and used for the Apache Camel 2.11 release.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work with Jetty 7.6.x as well. Any other ideas I should try ?